# Does increase of memory consumption in nodejs means memory leak?

Tags: node.js, memory-management, memory-leaks, v8, hapi.js

We use node v.10.32 in our production environment. There are 15 ui nodes and there are about 30000 users in the system during the peak hours.

Memory consumption in the servers are increasing after the last production release and we had to restart several times.Restarts were done when the memory consumption was more than 80%. Below graph shows the behaviors of the memory and cpu during last 7 days.Sudden drop in the Memory graph show a restart that happened on 16/16/9.

At the moment memory consumption is close to 70%.

[image: appdynamics memory graph]

Below node modules have been used to develop the application.

**"compression": "^1.6.1",
    "handlebars": "2.0.0",
    "hapi": "8.6.1",
    "jwt-simple": "^0.5.0",
    "moment": "^2.13.0",
    "request": "^2.65.0",
    "url": "^0.11.0"**

I need to know that, cause for this issue is a memory leak or not?

Comment: Your node and hapijs versions are very old.  Is there no way you can try with newer versions?

Comment: I'm investigating the issue. Next step would be to update nodejs and try. At the moment we can't afford to update hapijs.

Comment: The problem is your hapijs version was only developed onlong side older versions of node.

Comment: Just keep profiling.   if it grows forever, whether it's a "leak" or not, it's not suitable to your needs.  If it eventually plateaus, then it's not a leak.

Comment: @xaxxon profiling means to use the chrome dev tools to get js cpu profile? Is it possible to capture nodejs memory issues using chrome dev tools?

Comment: Whatever you're doing to get the graphs above, just keep doing it.   Eventually you will either run out of memory or it will plateau.

Comment: Currently what we do is restart after the limit of 75%. i'll conduct some tests to find out whether it plateau after that percentage.